# How to compress to .zip in C#

Tags: c#, compression, zip

What do I need to compress to .zip (not .gzip) in C# and how do I go about it?

I just need a quick answer, more preferably a link?

Thanks

Comment: -1 No prior research and not a real question. Try Google and Codeplex or just Searching SO.

Answer (score 3):

DotNetZip is a good option. (http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/)
It is pretty easy and quick.

```
Here is an example from the site:

Zip:
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
 {
     // add this map file into the "images" directory in the zip archive
     zip.AddFile("c:\\images\\personal\\7440-N49th.png", "images");
     // add the report into a different directory in the archive
     zip.AddFile("c:\\Reports\\2008-Regional-Sales-Report.pdf", "files");
     zip.AddFile("ReadMe.txt");
     zip.Save("MyZipFile.zip");
 }

 Extract:
 using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(ExistingZipFile))
 {
    zip.ExtractAll(TargetDirectory);    
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

http://sharpdevelop.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/